# Cloudformation: Cannot create ELB and DNSRecord together

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a whole stack of services through CloudFormation. The ELB is created and later the DNS Record Set for the ELB DNSName. The record set depends on the ELB.

```
"dns": {
  "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "HostedZoneName": "*******.com.",
    "RecordSets": [
      {
        "Name": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
              "\\052.",
              {
                "Ref": "EnvUrl"
              },
              ".******.com"
            ]
          ]
        },
        "Type": "A",
        "AliasTarget": {
          "HostedZoneId": "Z3******O77V",
          "DNSName": {"Fn::GetAtt": [ "elb", "DNSName" ]}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "Metadata": {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
      "id": "c1513eaa-fdaa-4fef-b50c-bdd178dd0446"
    }
  },
  "DependsOn": [
    "elb"
  ]
}



"elb": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
      "Properties": {
        "Policies": [
          {
            "PolicyName": "AWSConsole-SSLNegotiationPolicy",
            "PolicyType": "SSLNegotiationPolicyType",
            "Attributes": [
              {
                "Name": "Reference-Security-Policy",
                .......
```

The problem is that CloudFormation is not able to create the record set. The error:

```
Tried to create an alias that targets ctf21-elb-1huy2****pkn-727***38.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com,
type A in zone Z3******O77V, but the alias target name does not lie within the target zone
```

I believe that it might be due to the unavailability of the load balancer right after it is created. As if you create it manually, it wouldn't show right away in the alias selection field on Route53 but would need a few minutes.

I also tried to add `dualstack.-dnsname-` using `Fn::Join`, same output.

Is there something I am doing wrong? Is there something better than I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ELB zone is probably wrong.

Try this in the AliasTarget.

```
"AliasTarget": {
            "DNSName": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "elb", "DNSName" ]},
            "HostedZoneId": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "elb", "CanonicalHostedZoneNameID"]}
}
```

Comment: Aaaaah I thought I had to put my Route53 hosted zone ID here, I didn't realize ELB has another hosted zone ID for itself. I'll test now.

Comment: Worked nicely. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when you have a "dual stack" one.